# Android things (Raspberry Pi 3) BluetoothAdapter.startLEScan(..)

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-things

I'm trying to do:

`BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startLeScan()`

I've added all required permissions (as I think):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

*Please note that Android things does not support the runtime permissions regardless of it is running based on Android 7.0*

And what I am getting in the logs:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
```

As per documentation, It should be able to start scanning having all that permissions, but for some reason it does not want to.
I am using `0.4.0-devpreview` of Android Things on Raspberry Pi 3

Comment: Did you restart the device after requesting the permissions? or start the app with adb and the `-g` flag?

Comment: @Blundell, there multiple ways to start app from command line, so I'm not sure of which command you are talking about. Can you show an axample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reboot the device after the app has started to get access to the permissions

> Dangerous permissions requested by apps are not granted **until the next device reboot**. This includes new app installs and new  elements in existing apps.

https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html

Another way to force permissions to be given, is to start your app with `adb` and the `-g` flag (*this will be default in a future version of AndroidStudio*)

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
adb install -g app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

Comment: completely solving my problem!